# applying splash give me error You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-studio

in 23 we have these styles define by default now i have to start splash with full screen

vlue/stylefile

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

v21style file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

manifest:

```
 android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".User_MainInterface"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user__main_interface"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"></activity>
```

please help me to solve this problem quickly

Comment: your v21 style theme file does not inherit from theme.appcompat.

Comment: change this `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent =" AppTheme">`

Comment: The error message gives you the solution - "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)"

Comment: @Raghunandan the thing is i have two activities the splash open and works but when the oncreate of other activity call it gives me app compat descendent error

Comment: @HameesArshad all your activities must have theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat`. you can use inheritance and style them appropriately based on your requirement

Comment: @Raghunandan and how to do that?

Comment: @HameesArshad apply the same theme to second activity and if you need to customize do that in `AppTheme.NoActionBar` and apply the amse

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks finally it is working now

Answer (score 23):

If you are experiencing this error when implementing the new [**SplashScreen API**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate) for *[Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all)*, don't forget to `installSplashScreen`:

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
```

Don't forget to add this ***before*** `setContentView()`.

Comment: Life saver!  It might be worth while to move this answer to a question specific to SplashScreen API to save people some sifting.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not seem to work

Comment: @George feel free to take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 13):

In case is useful for anyone.

if you are using `androidx.core:core-splashscreen` and this error comes out, for me, using kotlin, what worked was:

calling `installSplashScreen()` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in the `onCreate` method.

Importing `import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen`

it should look similar to:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //other methods
}
```

Comment: I've been running into this silly crash for about 2 hours and this answer **WORKS**. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I started having this issue after updating my Kotlin and compose library versions but this fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

then...update your manifest of splash activity like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from **Android 12** and facing this issue? here's the only way it worked with me to both overcome the exception and hide actionbar:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/ed_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
    
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/ed_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is facing an issue after implementing Splash API (`androidx.core:core-splashscreen`) follow the below steps.

Define:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/ed_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
   <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
    <!-- Required -->
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme</item>

</style>
```

Then in Manifest check and verify that you given `Theme.App.Starting`

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting" > 
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Finally, Don't forget to add.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` to  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` for full screen

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue as well although I was calling `installSplashScreen()` properly in my main activity.

However, I was also using hilt injection, which means I had an extra activity I've created especially for hilt in automation tests.

In case someone is having the same issue, you need to call `installSplashScreen()` there as well, like you did in your main activity.

An example would be like:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltActivityForTest : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I RESOLEVED THIS PROBLEM:

i addes spash screen style AFTER my app them :

```
 <style name="Base.Theme.MyAppSplash" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>
<style name="Theme.MyAppSplash" parent="Base.Theme.MyAppSplash" />

 <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyAppSplash</item>
    </style>
```

and then in manifest :
add this line in activity:  `android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"`

```
<activity
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

in the end in your MainActivity add this line:  SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

if you are going to show loginactivity after splash screen , check this answer . so helpfull !
[Android 12 Splash Screen API - Increasing SplashScreen Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857274/android-12-splash-screen-api-increasing-splashscreen-duration)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this style
.

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

For splashscreen